# Broken %APPDATA%

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, user-profiles

I managed to break my %APPDATA% folder, by moving my user area from one hard drive to another.
I just moved (rightclick, move) the [Username] folder to another hard drive,
and ingnored a lot of the error messages (I forgot that %APPDATA% was stored in your user area). 
Anyway, now all my stuff that was in %APPDATA% is gone, 
eg my bookmarks, email accounts, even what is in the libraries, has been cleared. (Though the link to my user area still works).

Has anyone ever encountered something similar? Or got any idea about how I should go about repairing it? (Other than just resetting up my libraries and book marks, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a whole load of junction points in your user folder.

The best idea would be to make a new account, move your files and %appdata% settings over and delete your old account and profile.

Try to choose a slightly different username, otherwise your profile folder will be called username.001 or something like that, if it still works the same as it did with XP.